# backbone - heads git://github.com/test.git", exit cod

Tags: git, maven, backbone.js

While maven build my current project throws below issue

```
bower backbone.paginator#0.8.1  ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote   
--tags --heads git://github.com/test.git", exit code
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-  
plugin:1.7:run (1) on project project-name: An Ant BuildException has   
occured: exec returned: 1
```

Please help to fix below issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue you need to follow two steps

1) - Check permission on  git://github.com/test.git , try to open the git url(which shows in error console (red color )) in browser with the same user name and password which you are using in Jenkins.

2)- Some time due to some permission issue Jenkins not able to hit directly to git url using git,
So we need to update git config.
you can simply fire a command  which tells to use https instead of git

git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://

for more reference you can check this link as well [Link](http://pathakamit783.blogspot.in/2014/09/jenkins-issues.html)